# Очередь с++

Tags: c++

вот у меня есть код. тут у меня функции добавления элементов, я хочу в еще одной функции пользователя заполнить свою очередь рандомом от 1 до 100. Мне это нужно для задания. мое задание "поместить максимальный элемент очереди на первую позицию.".я так понимаю,что очередь мне надо пересобрать. Но для начала нужно хотя бы ее заполнить, по этому прошу у вас помощи. вот кусок кода с самой структурой очереди

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
struct queue
{
int data;
queue *next;
}*head, *tail, *head_pos, *tail_pos;
void push(queue **head, queue **tail, int data,)
{
queue *element=new queue;

element->data=data;
element->next=NULL;
if(*head==NULL)
*head=*tail=element;
else
{
(*tail)->next=element;
*tail=element;
}
}
void pop(queue ** head)
{
    *head=(*head)->next;
}
```

Comment: Желаю успеха.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы посоветовал посмотреть чуть глубже и сразу изменить структуры данных.

```
struct qitem {
  struct qitem *next, *prev;
  int data;
};  // элемент очереди. Очередь представлена ДВУСВЯЗНЫМ списком

struct queue {
  struct qitem *first, *last;
};  // заголовок очереди. В пустой очереди first = last = 0
```

Тогда (при правильной реализации нужных функций) задача решается буквально парой строчек

```
struct queue my_q = {0, 0};
struct qitem *add_head(struct queue *, struct qitem *),
             *add_tail(struct queue *, struct qitem *),
             *remove(struct queue *, struct qitem *),
             *find_max(struct queue *),
             *make_item(int);

// заполним очередь 
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   add_tail(&my_q, make_item((rand() % 100) + 1));

// теперь найдем максимум, вынем его из списка и вставим в начало
add_head(&my_q, remove(&my_q, find_max(&my_q)));
```

Прототипы функций я написал (названия замените на свой вкус), осталось их запрограммировать.

**UPDATE**

Вот что получилось

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat aq2.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct qitem { 
  struct qitem *next, *prev; 
  int data; 
};

struct queue { 
  struct qitem *first, *last; 
};

struct qitem *add_head (struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
  if (e) {
    e->prev = 0;
    if (e->next = q->first)
      q->first->prev = e;
    else
      q->last = e;
    q->first = e;
  }
  return e;
}

struct qitem  *add_tail (struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
  if (e) {
    e->next = 0;
    if (e->prev = q->last)
      q->last->next = e;
    else
      q->first = e;
    q->last = e;
  }
  return e;
}

struct qitem *remove (struct queue *q, struct qitem *e) {
  if (e) {
    if (e->next)
      e->next->prev = e->prev;
    else
      q->last = e->prev;
    if (e->prev)
      e->prev->next = e->next;
    else
      q->first = e->next;
  }
  return e;
}

struct qitem *find_max (struct queue *q) {
  struct qitem *cur = q->first, *pmax = cur;

  if (cur) {
    while (cur) {
      if (cur->data > pmax->data) 
    pmax = cur;
      cur = cur->next;
    }
  }

  return pmax;
}

struct qitem *make_item (int n) {
  struct qitem *p = new struct qitem;

  p->data = n;
  return p;
}

void print_list (struct queue *q) {
  cout << "queue " << q->first << " : " << q->last << '\n';
  for (struct qitem *cur = q->first; cur; cur = cur->next)
    cout << cur->data << 
      " [ " << cur <<": next " << cur->next << " prev " << cur->prev <<"]\n";
}

struct queue randlist (int n)
{
  struct queue my_q = {0, 0}; 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    add_tail(&my_q, make_item((rand() % 100) + 1));

  return my_q;
}

int main() {
  int N;

  cout << "Enter N: ";   cin >> N;

  struct queue my_q = randlist(N);
  print_list(&my_q);

  cout << "---- find max and move it to head ----\n";
  add_head(&my_q, remove(&my_q, find_max(&my_q))); 
  print_list(&my_q);

  cout << "---- free memory (remove all queue items and delete them) ----\n";
  struct qitem *p;
  int n = 0;
  while (p = remove(&my_q, my_q.first)) {
    delete p;
    n++;
  }
  cout << "remove " << n << " items\n";
  print_list(&my_q);

  if (n == N)
    cout << "OK!\n";
  else
    cout << "FAIL...\n";

  return N != n;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ aq2.cpp
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
Enter N: 7
queue 0xc21010 : 0xc210d0
84 [ 0xc21010: next 0xc21030 prev 0]
87 [ 0xc21030: next 0xc21050 prev 0xc21010]
78 [ 0xc21050: next 0xc21070 prev 0xc21030]
16 [ 0xc21070: next 0xc21090 prev 0xc21050]
94 [ 0xc21090: next 0xc210b0 prev 0xc21070]
36 [ 0xc210b0: next 0xc210d0 prev 0xc21090]
87 [ 0xc210d0: next 0 prev 0xc210b0]
---- find max and move it to head ----
queue 0xc21090 : 0xc210d0
94 [ 0xc21090: next 0xc21010 prev 0]
84 [ 0xc21010: next 0xc21030 prev 0xc21090]
87 [ 0xc21030: next 0xc21050 prev 0xc21010]
78 [ 0xc21050: next 0xc21070 prev 0xc21030]
16 [ 0xc21070: next 0xc210b0 prev 0xc21050]
36 [ 0xc210b0: next 0xc210d0 prev 0xc21070]
87 [ 0xc210d0: next 0 prev 0xc210b0]
---- free memory (remove all queue items and delete them) ----
remove 7 items
queue 0 : 0
OK!
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ echo $?
0
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Я так понял (из Вашего комментария), что Вы решили сгенерить список в отдельной функции.
Я назвал ее `randlist` и передаю параметром размер очереди.

Обратите внимание, `randlist()` возвращает *значение* структуры `queue` (реально копируются 2 указателя - 16 байт на 64-бит компе (8 на 32-бит)), которое присваивается такой же структуре в `main`. Поскольку память под нее не выделяется через `new`, то и удалять ее не надо.

Остальная часть задачи (ввод, вызов печати и т.п. в `main`).

Печатаю значение (`data`), адрес самого элемента очереди и адреса следующего и предыдущего элементов.

При удалении очереди подсчитываю число удаляемых элементов. Сначала элемент извлекается из очереди (корректируются все указатели *на него*), а затем он удаляется.

При желании можете попробовать повторить все (можно с другим N) после удаления. Элементы должны вновь занимать ту же память (смотрите адреса в печати очереди).

Постарайтесь разобраться, лучше всего написав свои комментарии. Что непонятно, спрашивайте (но время позднее, ответить уже могу и не успеть:)).

Comment: Cep, гляньте пожалуйста, правильно ли я записала то, что вы сказали. И еще вопрос: как правильно в функцию мейн передать значение,чтобы мою очередь вывести. И как удалить потом память. Я же выходит выделяю, но не удаляю. Для этого стоит создать отдельную функцию?

Comment: @Anna992, Вы себя не обижайте, все получится.

Код, конечно, лучше приводить в вопросе (его можно править, отмечайте новый там **update** (или что-то в этом роде)), а не в комментариях. В комментариях его форматировать очень неудобно, да и их количество ограничено (4 шт.)

--

Я напишу, где-то полчасика займет, но Вы уж не взыщите (если ошибочки будут...)

Comment: Написал в **UPDATE** моего ответа.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Вы меня спасли. Я все разберу и если что спрошу, но постараюсь сама разобрать. Еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0):

немного глупости:

```
#include<iostream> //главная библиотека  С++
#include<stdlib.h> //главная библиотека  С
/* в теге к вопросу у вас "С++" но пишите вы в стиле "С" (а выделяете память в стиле С++)*/ 
/* так что определитесь и не используйте обе*/
```

---

---

---

на данный момент у вас всегда добавляется всё в конец...
вы сделайте функцию сравнения двух структур (которая определит больше\меньше\равно)

и вызывайте её в `push(...)`, и соответственно если значение больше то кидать его в начало очереди, так с самого начала заполнение очереди будет в порядке уменьшения (голова будет с наибольшим значением)

---

---

---

если же вам надо "создать, а потом найти и вставить в начало максимальный элемент" то просто добавьте 3 функции **`найти_максимум(...)`**, **`вырезать_из_середины_очереди(...)`**, **`вставить_в_начало()`**

---

---

---

ну и на десерт:

дорогая Анна вам как начинающему программисту многое простительно, а если учесть ваш пол то простительно практически всё! НО почитайте что такое "[утечка памяти](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)" и как "бравый программер" соизвольте удалить то что выделили, а то у вас утечка в `pop()`